# get the ID in Javascript as variable from embedded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I am trying to get the id of the video of an embedded script.  This ID changes each time for the video so I would need to grab it somehow.

This is the embed line that is added in the HTML document:

```
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/players/80HZjDPO-V5C9t34F.js"></script>
```

This is what it generates:

```
<div id="botr_80HZjDPO_V5C9t34F_div" class="jwplayer jw-reset jw-state-paused jw-stretch-uniform jw-flag-aspect-mode jw-breakpoint-4 jw-flag-user-inactive" tabindex="0" aria-label="Video Player" role="application" style="width: 100%;">
```

This is the id I want to grab:

```
id="botr_80HZjDPO_V5C9t34F_div"
```

I noticed that this is always the same:

```
botr_ ****** _V5C9t34F_div
```

How would I be able to grab this id and use it in my Javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('jwplayer')[0].id`

Comment: @ChrisG While ^ that does work in some circumstances, it won't work in others.  What if there are more than 1 elements on the page with that class?  When including a script from a remote Url you have no guarantees that the generated code will ever be the same.  It works, but is in no way reliable.

Comment: Why do you want the ID?

Comment: I agree and confirm, in my case does not work. @Archer: I need to id to be able to connect to an analytics system

Comment: @Archer the post does not specify that there will be more than one instances. The question was answered, in the best way possibile.

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk OP has already confirmed that it does not work.  Post does not specify either way, so that comment was based on assumption, which is why it was incorrect.

Comment: @Archer i see, but for how the question is, it was the best answer. If it does not work it means that there is something else that the OP has not specified

Comment: @Archer I'm obviously aware that my comment only works for a single video, but one can easily replace `document` with a suitable parent element.

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk It's not an answer - it's a comment, just like my comment.  This isn't worth discussing.

Comment: @ChrisG More assumption - the videos are all in distinct parent containers.  Just accept the criticism **_that helped the OP._**

Comment: I was just about to propose to @ChrisG to repost as an answer :)

Comment: the only criticism to do is that jQuery was requested

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk OP did not *request* jQuery.  The tag on the question simply means that they are using it, so answers can also use it.

Comment: @EwaldBos You should mark the answer as accepted, if it's helped you :)

Comment: @Archer I have absolutely no problem with valid criticism. My comment was supposed to point out a simple and obvious solution, and not meant as a catch-all answer (otherwise I might have posted it as such)

Comment: @Archer You assume that your criticism is valid... just kidding :) I try to be as tone-neutral as possible, but text-only is always ambiguous, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$` in the attribute selector to match the end of the string `$("div[id$='_V5C9t34F_div']")`.

> **[name$=”value”]**
>
> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified
>   attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The
>   comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: this works:     var test2 = $("div[id$='_V5C9t34F_div']");
    console.log(test2[0].id)

Comment: @EwaldBos yes. Glad to help :)

Comment: Alternative to this... `document.querySelector("div[id$='_V5C9t34F_div']").id`  Same principle but vanilla JS

Comment: i noticed that is only takes the last part of the id-string "_V5C9t34F_div" as example, this does not work "_V5C9t34F" why is that? And is it possible as well to take a part of the string or the start. How does it work?

Comment: @EwaldBos `[id$=XXX]` means, find all elements where the ID ends with XXX.  You could change it to `[id*=XXX]`, which will find all elements with XXX anywhere in the ID.

Comment: very nice, it now searches on the subscription number: V5C9t34F :)